# Erro ao tentar exibir dados do banco utilizando Handlebars

Tags: node.js, express.js, handlebars.js

O Handlebars está me retornando este erro toda vez que acesso a página html, ele recebe os valores do banco mas não exibe. Estou usando o Mongo como banco.
Podem me dizer se é algum erro de versão ou se estou fazendo algo errado?

"
Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "nome" because it is not an "own property" of its parent.
You can add a runtime option to disable the check or this warning:
See https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to-control-prototype-access for details
"

Minha rota

```
router.get('/categorias', (req,res) => {

    Categoria.find().then((categorias) => {

        res.render('admin/categorias.handlebars',{categorias:categorias});
        console.log(categorias);

    }).catch((err) => {
        req.flash('error_msg',"Houve um erro ao listar as categorias"+err);
        res.redirect('http://localhost:8080/admin');

    });
});
```

Minha página html

```
{{#each categorias}}
    <div class="card mt-4">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4>Nome: {{name}}</h4>
        </div>
    </div>

{{else}}

{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Resposta encontrada.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59753149/express-handlebars-wont-render-data)

```
router.get('/categorias', (req,res) => {

    Categoria.find().sort({date:'desc'}).lean().then((categorias) => {

        res.render('admin/categorias.handlebars',{categorias:categorias});
        console.log(categorias);

    }).catch((err) => {
        req.flash('error_msg',"Houve um erro ao listar as categorias"+err);
        res.redirect('http://localhost:8080/admin');

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get('/categorias', (req,res) => {
   
   Categoria.find().map(categories => () {
       const results = {
         name: categories.name,
       }
       return results;
    })

    res.render('admin/categorias.handlebars',{categorias:categorias});
        console.log(categorias);

    }).catch((err) => {
        req.flash('error_msg',"Houve um erro ao listar as categorias"+err);
        res.redirect('http://localhost:8080/admin');

    });
});
```

Comment: Amigo se possível comente sua resposta e destaque a parte que foi modificada, isso ajuda outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida.